# get value of method or variable with same code

Tags: javascript

```
var n = {
     a: 1,
     b: function() {
          return Math.random();
     }
}
```

How would i get the value of any method or variable in the object **n** in a simpler manner?
Right now my solution is:

```
get = 'b';
typeof n[get] === 'function' ? n[get]() : n[get]; //returns a random number

get = 'a';
typeof n[get] === 'function' ? n[get]() : n[get]; //returns 1
```

Is it required to check the type to get the value of either **n.a** or **n.b**? Neither of these suffice on their own:

```
n[get] // fails to retrieve return value of n.b
n[get]() //throws an error retrieving value of n.a
```

Comment: use `eval`: `eval("typeof " + n[get] + " == 'function'") ? n[get]() : n.get`

Comment: yes, it is required to check the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your object differently using [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), you can specify setters and getters for a specific property:

```
o = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  a: { value: 1 },
  b: {
    configurable: false,
    get: function() { return Math.random(); }
}});

console.log( o.a );  // just 1
console.log( o.b );  // random value
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [mozilla's "get" page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get), the simplest answer after refining Sirko's answer would be:

```
var o = {
  a: 1,
  get b() {
    return Math.random();
  }
}

console.log( o.a );  // returns 1
console.log( o.b );  // random value
```

this removes the need to use Object.create.